# Assigning values to a bunch of objects from a vector

Tags: python

I am doing a simulation programming where there are some objects whose states, represented as object fields, need to be periodically updated from another vector or consecutively stored data.

I understand that a straightforward way is to iterate with indices and do the manual assignment in a loop:

```
for i in range(0, obj_count):
  dest[i].field1 = src_vec[i+constant]
```

But I find it somewhat awkward since you need to calculate the right indices to use in the source and destinations. Is there a way to do this without explicitly using indices that does this "synchronization" task? Or from a design perspective, is it better to use a central data structure to store the states that need to be tracked instead of using individual objects?

Comment: I think we need more context on this. Presumably the attributes are immutable? What is `constant`?

Comment: @roganjosh the added `constant` is a trivial example to show that the source and destination data may not be aligned, i.e., the indices used at one place need to be translated to index at another place.